# Where can I find a modern overview of Luvian hieroglyphs?

Tags: reference-request, anatolian, luwian

According to Melchert, the reading of Hieroglyphic Luvian (HLuvian, HLuwian) was completely revolutionized in 1974 by Hawkins, Morpurgo-Davies, and Neumann.

However, I haven't been able to find an overview of HLuvian writing that incorporates these "new readings": an inventory of signs with their readings, an explanation of the use of logograms and determiners, etc.

Does such an overview exist? If so, where would I find one? (The more modern the better; I don't know how much readings have changed since 1974 but I assume there's been some progress there.)

Comment: https://www.degruyter.com/view/title/5104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read Payne:
https://books.google.fr/books/about/Hieroglyphic_Luwian.html?id=x_F71ge6-EIC which is a textbook (I have it as a book)
There's also the very huge book by John David Hawkins:
https://books.google.fr/books?id=yZKJq5A6drwC
This book is quite a marvel. (I have it as a pdf)

Comment: Excellent! Does Hawkins go into the intricacies of how the writing system works, or is it just a corpus with translations? (I can't tell from Google's blurb.)

Comment: yes, Hawkins also describes how the system works, especially those signs that are really the core of the system, and those who work differently.

Comment: Excellent; I've picked up a copy of Hawkins through the library and I like his explanations a lot.